# How can I hide activities with no user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause, public-activity

I'm trying to hide activities where their owners have deleted their accounts. So I added this

```
PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where( recipient: current_user).where.not(owner: nil)
```

but it returns

```
undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass
```

meaning it's adding activities with deleted users to the record. How can I hide them?

Comment: you are not making any calls to 'image' on that line, can you run that line on your rails console and still gives you the same error?

Comment: I am calling images in the view, the thing is since this is happening then the record is including activities with owner: nil. In the console (with same users) it returns #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: can you share the line of the view that is giving you problems

Comment: I tried like 5 different ways, the error is coming from (activity.owner.image).  since the user no more exists

Comment: you could try something like this `<%= activity.owner.image.id if activity.owner.image %>`

Comment: No, I need to not include the activity from the first place in the record, thanks for the help tho

Comment: Your code seems correct. Still, you may try: `PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where("recipient = ? && owner IS NOT NULL", current_user)`

Comment: @Abhi retuned PublicActivity::Activity.order("created_at DESC").where("recipient = ? && owner IS NOT NULL", current_user)

Comment: @MalekZalfana I didn't get you. If you tried the above, what's the outcome?

Comment: @abhi I replied with the outome of your recommendation and the error in question